# CSS Buttons on different platforms

Tags: html, ios, css, background-color, platform

CSS Buttons when viewed on windows desktop or apple mac have a default background color of grey (#DDD) but when viewed on ios mobile, the default background color is transparent. This can be fixed by manually adding css background color as #DDD but still why does this happen? Any Ideas?

Comment: Show come code... Many people use divs as custom buttons

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach this kind of behavior might [break accessibility](https://medium.engineering/five-goofy-things-medium-did-that-break-accessibility-3bc804ae818d).

Comment: You can create your own "button" to get around this problem of browser's having their own button styles. Just use a class on a div that makes it look and behave exactly like a button would, but its **not** a button! `Genius`

Comment: It is a pure CSS button. No divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They look different because browsers have different renderings of CSS.

I recommend to use -webkit and -moz to avoid this type of problem.

```
.btn{
  -webkit-background-color: #DDD;
  -moz-background-color: #DDD;
   background-color: #DDD;
 }
```

Comment: Understood. Different browsers have different default css stylesheets and css renderings.

Comment: webkit like tags are no longer required for the new browser updates.

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers have different styles for `button`s, `select` dropdown, `input` file upload buttons.

These styles are taken from the default stylesheets present in the browser.

In order to avoid these default stylings, you have to reset the styles using CSS reset stylesheets like [Normalize CSS](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), [Meyers CSS](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) reset.

Reset for button only

```
button {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
    overflow: visible;

    background: transparent;

    /* inherit font & color from ancestor */
    color: inherit;
    font: inherit;

    /* Normalize `line-height`. Cannot be changed from `normal` in Firefox 4+. */
    line-height: normal;

    /* Corrects font smoothing for webkit */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: inherit;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: inherit;

    /* Corrects inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/* Remove excess padding and border in Firefox 4+ */
&::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```